# Laravel MIX Copy Directory Error in NPM WATCH

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

This is my laravel mix file. If I run development the file copied properly.

"NPM RUN DEV"

`mix.copyDirectory('resources/editorhome/',  'public/editorhome/' );`

actual copy path : D:\Projects\editster_v3\public\editorhome\a.js

But

"NPM RUN WATCH" file path copy error same code goes error.

```php

D:\Projects\editster_v3\public\editorhome\resources\editorhome\a.js

```

the source path upended.